# Make the Facebook crawler ignore the Canonical link

Tags: facebook-opengraph, canonical-link

I wonder if there is a way to make the Facebook crawler ignore the canonical link on a page.
I have a situation where the canonical link points to a different URL than the one that you are actually on.
This results in that the og:image, og:url etc. that is dynamically added to the page is ignored and the information on the facebook page is completely wrong.

I have searched for an answers to this but come up short...

Comment: can you post code or a link to your page

Comment: No I'm sorry I can't post code, but the thing is that if there are a canonical link on the page where your facebook like but is then the crawler used by facebook will use that link to find the "actual" page to crawl. But the thing is that this link due to about 80 markets in 160 languages points to another page than the one that you are actual on since we don't want Google to crawl all languages. So this results in all my og:image, og:title etc. are being ignored since they don't exist on the page that the canonical link point to. Is this information helpful?

Comment: not really. Without seeing the code its not possible to debug.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your comments correctly, you may be going about this the wrong way. If you want your like button to like a url different to the page you are on, just change the href of the like button. Make sure the page at that href has the correct og tags and you shouldn't have a problem.

If this isn't what you mean, can you try to explain what you are trying to achieve, rather than what you think the problem is, as you might just be approaching it from the wrong angle.

Comment: It's my understanding that the facebook crawler use the canonical link to find the correct page, if one is used. The problem I'm having is that I´m not getting the crawler to find the og: -tags I have added to the meta tags in the page header. And when I debug the page in the Facebook debuger the crawler is linked to the page that the canonical link is pointing at.

Comment: I get the url from the href correct since that one is specified on the likebutton href attribute but the image and title etc. added to the meta tags are not found. So i get the wrong image etc.